# How to move Time Machine backups from an AirPort Time Capsule to a NAS

Tags: backup, time-machine, time-capsule, nas

What steps should be taken to move an existing Time Machine backup from an AirPort Time Capsule to a NAS?

Apple describes how to do this when the source and destination are both AirPort Time Capsules: [How to move Time Machine backups from one AirPort Time Capsule to another](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204078)

**My initial approach**

1. Setup NAS per the [QNAP instructions for multiple Macs](https://www.qnap.com/en/how-to/tutorial/article/using-time-machine-to-back-up-your-mac-to-a-qnap-nas-via-smb) resulting in a SMB shared folder on its own volume and a corresponding user with Read/Write permission to the shared folder
2. Connect to the Time Capsule "Data" share from the Mac
3. Connect to the NAS share from the Mac, using the QNAP instructions for multiple Macs
4. Drag the sparse bundle from the "Data" share to the NAS shared folder
5. Point Time Machine on the Mac to the NAS shared folder